# rxjs distinct not working with firestore query

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, distinct

I am trying to get distinct firestore values (client side) with rxjs in angular with `distinct()`.  I get the same results as before.

```
{ id: '2224', city: 'chicago', name: 'jon' },
{ id: '33', city: 'chicago', name: 'bill' },
{ id '223' city: 'chicago', name: 'jon' }
```

Here is my code:

```js
query = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('city' '==', 'chicago'))
.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
.pipe(
  distinct((a: any) => a.name)
);
```

I get all the results as if the **pipe** is not present.

Going off of the [official doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinct), I would expect to get this:

```
{ id: '2224', city: 'chicago', name: 'jon' },
{ id: '33', city: 'chicago', name: 'bill' }
```

Should I just manually use a **switchMap** or something instead to filter the results?

Comment: I think you get the data in a single emission, as an array. you woukd probably need to remove duplicated manualy

Comment: Isn't that what ```distinct()``` is for? That is exactly how it works in the official example...

Comment: In the given example they are individual observables, like one emission is `{ age: 4, name: 'Foo'},` and next emission is `{ age: 7, name: 'Bar'},`, if this is the case, you can compare the values, I think what you get its an Array, you can pipe the array use a mergeeMap with distict

Comment: The easy way would be to simply remove filter out the response based on your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, using `distinct()` is not an apt tool for your usecase. You are getting a full array as a response, `distinct` would work on individual emissions.

You can convert the array to individual emissions and there you can see `distict()` working as desired.

```
this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('city' '==', 'chicago'))
.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
.pipe(
 mergeMap((allDocs) => {
        return from(allDocs).pipe(distinct((eachDoc) => {
            return eachDoc.name;
        }))
    })
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Here you would not get second 'Bill', BUT, I don't think you want a response of this sort, here you would be getting individual objects instead of an Array. This would mean, your subscription callback would be called same number of times, the inner observable emits.

**Solution:**
You can instead filter out the array reposne yourself, something like this can be an good solution for you:

```
this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('city' '==', 'chicago'))
  .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
  .pipe(
    map((allDocs) => {
      const auxObj = allDocs.reduce((acc, eachDoc) => {
        acc[eachDoc.name] = eachDoc;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      return Object.values(auxObj);
    })
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('filtered data', data);
})
```